# Where are the Node-js logs stored in curl operation?

Tags: mysql, node.js

i am perform any curl operation then all operation to action store log file
like create operation action perform to store action and req data

```
example: create action

logfile store: create: {"first":"abc", "last":"xyz","mobile":0123456789}
               update: {"first":"abc", "last":"xyz","mobile":0123456789}
```